# how to remove border in iOS components

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swift, uisearchbar

I've not understand why my components has this black pixel line - for example the `UISearchBar` on the screenshot. How to remove that? It's not tint.

[image]

EDIT:

the options of `UISearchBar` are:

[image]

the options of the Controller hosting the `UISearchBar` are:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Xcode 6. Then go to Storyboard select `UISearchBar` and click on **Show the Attribute Inspector**

In that change **Search Style** >> Default to Minimal.

[image]

Comment: thanks! Here It is! my searchbar textfield is now gray, how to put It white?

Comment: Change property to prominent will make it white.

Comment: prominent will keep the black line pixel and the first problem remain unresolved.

Comment: Ok. Let me check for how we can change search text field color background.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, that's just the background color.
Try to change the background color of the view.
If you are handling that in the **UIViewController**
Then, use the following codes to change the background color to transparent:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: hey Lucas. I've edited with the settings of the view, I don't think It's a background problem. On .h and .m files I haven't set any background color.